# Accumulate Price Change for Items in powerbi

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

hello everyone i have a [PBIX File](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ag9tIyk2ofNRlCILuPQgzNyKjBqJ?e=lv9rRy) and [Excel Dataset](https://1drv.ms/x/s!Ag9tIyk2ofNRlCPUFWLRgCkvroAZ?e=emRrTW)

it includes various tables of item , price change, discounts ...

i want to know how can i accumulate a price change percentage on my original price per item . all data modeling and datasets are found in the PBIX file .

so for example for item I-10 , no price change was recorder until Feb 14 2023 where the original price was 90 but now with the -0.5% so before feb 14 2023 it should be 90$ but from feb 14 2023 and after , it should be 90 + ( 90 * -0.005) which is 89.5$ and on april 28 , 2023 another price decrease of -0.20% happened so in total now it should calculate after april 28 2023 , 90 + ( 90 * -0.007) 89.2$
any ways to achieve that ?